# ASA 5505 vLAN Routing - 2 LAN 1 WAN

Tags: cisco, cisco-asa

I am setting up a Cisco ASA 5505 with the base license.

TCP/UDP communication works from inside->outside, outside->inside, inside->secure, which is my desired traffic security.

HTTP, SSH, and other access from inside->secure works, but I can't ping from inside->secure  (192.168.110.0 host to 192.168.7.1 or 192.168.7.0 host).

How can I enable ICMP?

Configuration:

```
interface Vlan1
 nameif inside
 security-level 100
 ip address 192.168.110.254 255.255.255.0 
!
interface Vlan2
 nameif outside
 security-level 0
 pppoe client vpdn group birdie
 ip address removedIP 255.255.255.255 pppoe 
!
interface Vlan3
 no forward interface Vlan1
 nameif secure
 security-level 50
 ip address 192.168.7.1 255.255.255.0 
!             
interface Ethernet0/0
 switchport access vlan 2
!             
interface Ethernet0/1
!             
interface Ethernet0/2
!             
interface Ethernet0/3
!             
interface Ethernet0/4
 switchport access vlan 3
!             
interface Ethernet0/5
 shutdown     
!             
interface Ethernet0/6
 shutdown     
!             
interface Ethernet0/7
 shutdown     
!             
ftp mode passive
clock timezone EST -5
clock summer-time EDT recurring
access-list Outside-In extended permit icmp any any 
access-list Outside-In extended permit tcp any any eq www 
access-list Outside-In extended permit tcp any any eq https 
access-list Outside-In extended permit tcp any any eq 5969 
access-list inside_nat0_outbound extended permit ip any 192.168.111.0 255.255.255.224 
access-list standardUser_splitTunnelAcl1 extended permit ip 192.168.111.0 255.255.255.0 any 
access-list standardUser_splitTunnelAcl1 extended permit ip 192.168.110.0 255.255.255.0 any 
access-list inside_in extended permit icmp any any 
access-list inside_in extended permit ip any any 
access-list secure_in extended permit icmp any any 
access-list secure_in extended permit ip any any 
pager lines 24
logging enable
logging asdm informational
mtu inside 1492
mtu outside 1492
mtu secure 1500 
ip local pool vpnuser 192.168.111.5-192.168.111.20
icmp unreachable rate-limit 1 burst-size 1
asdm image disk0:/asdm-524.bin
no asdm history enable
arp timeout 14400
nat-control   
global (outside) 1 interface
nat (inside) 0 access-list inside_nat0_outbound
nat (inside) 1 0.0.0.0 0.0.0.0
nat (secure) 1 192.168.7.0 255.255.255.0
static (inside,outside) tcp interface https 192.168.110.6 https netmask 255.255.255.255 
static (inside,outside) tcp interface www 192.168.110.6 www netmask 255.255.255.255 
static (inside,outside) tcp interface 5969 192.168.110.12 5969 netmask 255.255.255.255 
static (inside,secure) 192.168.110.0 192.168.110.0 netmask 255.255.255.0 
access-group inside_in in interface inside
access-group Outside-In in interface outside
access-group secure_in in interface secure
route outside 0.0.0.0 0.0.0.0 RemovedIP 1
```

Answer (score 1):

The only thing that looks odd to me in your config is the `static(inside,secure)` statement. It seems to be a no-op since the mapped and real addresses are the same. In my config, I have a dmz type network, too, and no `static(inside,dmz)` statement. (I do have `static(dmz,outside) ...` for externally-exposed services).

Anyway, try removing that static and see what effect that has.